# How to close stdout and stderr in C?

Tags: c, stdout, stderr

I need to close stdout and stderr for one of my C program. How is it possible without exiting the program in execution?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you close them?

Comment: @Joseph He might want to put the process in background. In this case you're always better to close all standard file descriptors so that you won't end up having them invalidated.

Comment: I just wanted to direct the stdout and stderr output to a log file instead of console. Sorry for answering late. I have got it working now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What have you tried? Doesn't `fclose` work?

Comment: @lhf so how to open it again ?

Comment: @entropy, there is no way to open it again.

Comment: you can reopen it using freopen("/dev/tty","w",stdout); This is often used if a call to execl fails.

Comment: Is close any of the 3 default streams dangerous, with potentially persistent ramifications for the actual machine you ran the executable on?

Answer (score 57):

You can just:

```
fclose(stdout);
fclose(stderr);
```

For anybody wondering why you might want to do this, this is a fairly common task for a daemon/service process on Unix.

**However** you should be aware that closing a file descriptor may have unintended consequences:

- When you open new files these now free descriptors will be used. So, for example, if you subsequently `fopen` that file descriptor (on Linux, at least) will replace fd 1, i.e. stdout. Any code that subsequently uses this will write to this file, which may not be what you intended.
- See R..'s comments on file descriptors versus C library `FILE*` pointers. Specifically:

  - If you write to a closed fd under Linux, you'll get an error, but:
  - If you use a C library function that uses `stdout` or `stderr` (which are `FILE*` pointers (see [their definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html)) then writing to these whilst `FILE*` is closed is undefined behaviour. This will likely crash your program in unexpected ways, not always at the point of the bug either. See [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- Your code isn't the only part affected. Any libraries you use, and any processes you launch which inherited these file descriptors as their standard descriptors are also affected.

The quick, one-line solution is to [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freopen.html) To say `/dev/null`, `/dev/console` under Linux/OSX or `nul` on Windows. Alternatively, you can use your platform-specific implementation to re-open the file descriptors/handles as required.

Comment: ...the reason for doing it is to disassociate the process from the tty that started it (if it was started from a tty).

Comment: Closing them without opening a replacement (e.g. `/dev/null`) is a very bad idea and generally dangerous.

Comment: You got the reason wrong. Writing to a closed `FILE` (stdio stream) is UB, but writing to a closed file descriptor is just `EBADF`. In any case, the more important reason is that another part of the program or child process might later open an important file, which will get assigned the first unused file descriptor number. If fd 0, 1, or 2 is unused, the new file descriptor will take the place of stdin, stdout, or stderr, and could get clobbered by another part of the program (or child process) that uses any of these for their usual purposes...

Comment: -1. This is still bad advice and it turns up on Google. *Don't* fclose stderr, that's probably a bad bug. `freopen()` stderr to /dev/null or do `dup2(somenullfd,2)`.

Comment: @NicholasWilson yes, I know. I addressed that issue at the time, however, to make it more explicit, I've re-written the answer to incorporate all of the above comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to prevent your application from writing to the console, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    fprintf(stdout, "stdout: msg1\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "stderr: msg1\n");
    fclose(stdout);

    fprintf(stdout, "stdout: msg2\n");  // Please read the note setion below
    fprintf(stderr, "stderr: msg2\n");
    fclose(stderr);

    fprintf(stdout, "stdout: msg3\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "stderr: msg3\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
stdout: msg1
stderr: msg1
stderr: msg2
```

**Note:** any attempt to use a FILE pointer after the file is closed is erroneous. I'm doing it in this case just to illustrate what closing these file descriptors *might* do to your application.

Comment: This code has undefined behavior (using a `FILE *` after the file was closed). It could just as well crash or worse.

Comment: @R That part of the code you mentioned is just to illustrate what the application does since the questioner didn't answered our comments about what he expected to happen after closing stdout/stderr. Since I added a warning in the answer about this, I'm not sure I still deserve the -1, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I removed the -1, but "will do" is still erroneous. Saying this is what it "might do" would be better, but either way you should note that the example code has *undefined behavior* and is an incorrect program.

Answer (score 3):

*Warning: I am not experienced in C at all, but recently read a slide that answers this question directly by Jim Meyering, a RedHat employee and GNUlib maintainer: https://www.gnu.org/ghm/2011/paris/slides/jim-meyering-goodbye-world.pdf. I merely summarize.*

#### TL;DR

Get [closeout.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/closeout.c) and its dependencies from GNUlib into your source and call

```
atexit(close_stdout);
```

as your first line in main.

#### Summary

First, some heads up warning, quoting [POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=555):

> Since after the call to fclose() any use of stream results in undefined behavior, fclose() should not be used on stdin, stdout, or stderr except immediately before process termination, ...... If there are any atexit() handlers registered by the application, such a call to fclose() should not occur until the last handler is finishing. Once fclose() has been used to close stdin, stdout, or stderr, there is no standard way to reopen any of these streams.
>
> Usage of close() on file descriptors STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO or STDERR_FILENO should immediately be followed by an operation to reopen these file descriptors. ...... Furthermore, a close() followed by a reopen operation (e.g. open(), dup() etc) is not atomic; dup2() should be used to change standard file descriptors.

Closing stream without handling its errors is not robust, and it is the same for stdout and stderr. Here is a list of errors you need to handle:

- `fclose(stdout)`
- `ferror(stdout)` a.k.a. previous error
- `__fpending(stdout)` a.k.a. stuff not flushed

Handling these errors, as GNUlib implements in [close-stream.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/close-stream.c), is quoted below.

```
int
close_stream (FILE *stream)
{
  const bool some_pending = (__fpending (stream) != 0);
  const bool prev_fail = (ferror (stream) != 0);
  const bool fclose_fail = (fclose (stream) != 0);

  /* Return an error indication if there was a previous failure or if
     fclose failed, with one exception: ignore an fclose failure if
     there was no previous error, no data remains to be flushed, and
     fclose failed with EBADF.  That can happen when a program like cp
     is invoked like this 'cp a b >&-' (i.e., with standard output
     closed) and doesn't generate any output (hence no previous error
     and nothing to be flushed).  */

  if (prev_fail || (fclose_fail && (some_pending || errno != EBADF)))
    {
      if (! fclose_fail)
        errno = 0;
      return EOF;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Notice: `__fpending` is special to glibc and may not be portable. OTOH, it is [on the way to be standardized](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2012-06/msg00201.html) as `fpending`.

P.S.:

> I just wanted to direct the stdout and stderr output to a log file instead of console.

That is not a good reason to close stdout and stderr if you are writing a daemon according to http://cloud9.hedgee.com./scribbles/daemon#logging. You should let a daemon manager (such as daemon tools, runit, s6, nosh, OpenRC and systemd) handle the redirection.

However, you still should close any stream that the program has ever written to in the end to check for errors. Quote from close-stream.c:

> If a program writes *anything* to STREAM, that program should close
>      STREAM and make sure that it succeeds before exiting.  Otherwise,
>      suppose that you go to the extreme of checking the return status
>      of every function that does an explicit write to STREAM.  The last
>      printf can succeed in writing to the internal stream buffer, and yet
>      the fclose(STREAM) could still fail (due e.g., to a disk full error)
>      when it tries to write out that buffered data.  Thus, you would be
>      left with an incomplete output file and the offending program would
>      exit successfully.  Even calling fflush is not always sufficient,
>      since some file systems (NFS and CODA) buffer written/flushed data
>      until an actual close call.
>
> Besides, it's wasteful to check the return value from every call
>      that writes to STREAM -- just let the internal stream state record
>      the failure.  That's what the ferror test is checking below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also use the `close` function:

```
#include<unistd.h> // close
#include<stdio.h>  // STDOUT_FILENO,STDERR_FILENO
...
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this about stdout. It will not close stdout, but it will redirect stdout to NULL. I believe you could do the same for stderr. It worked in my situation (Linux/GCC) (It should works in both Unix and Windows, but I have not test in Windows).

```
//saving current stdout descriptor
FILE oldstdout = *stdout;
//open a output stream to null
FILE *mystdout = fopen("/dev/null", "w"); //to unix
if( !mystdout )        
    mystdout = fopen("NUL", "w"); // to Windows

*stdout = *mystdout; //replacing stdout by our stream to null

/*******  PUT YOUR CODE HERE TO BE "MUTED" *******/

//enabling back stdout 
*stdout = oldstdout;
fclose(mystdout);   //closing my null stream
```

The advantage of this solution is stdout is never closed. So, the original stdout can be restored at any time as it is necessary. We also do not have any risk of stdout file descriptor be assigned to another output stream.