# Can input/output via respective standard I/O streams fail?

Tags: c, file-io, c99

Standard input/output functions such as `fgets` and `fputs` may fail on respective read or write errors. This makes sense as filesystem permissions and space constraints may prevent a program from reading or writing a file.

However, I'm having a hard time imagining a situation where an input/output operation on the respective standard I/O stream (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`) would fail, as they appear to be conceptually more abstract than a typical file in the filesystem.

For example, is it ever possible for the following `fputs` call to return an `EOF` signifying a write error?

```
fputs("Hello world!\n", stdout)
```

Does the C99 standard explicitly, or implicitly, guarantee successful input/output operations on respective standard I/O streams; or is a failure possible on a compliant theoretical implementation?

I suspect that errors are possible on standard I/O streams as both the `puts` function and `gets` function **Returns** sections mention the possibility of failure return values; with `puts` and `gets` explicitly writing/reading respectively to the `stdout`/`stdin` streams, errors on the standard I/O streams appear to be implicit.

However, does the same apply to the `stderr` stream? Possibly not, as the `perror` function does not mention error conditions, nor return values signifying failure (`perror` has a `void` return type).

Comment: Input functions, by their very definition, can't get errors for *output* operations. Also, your example is flawed as [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) will never return `EOF`.

Comment: Failure's always possible. Imagine the case where your process is in the middle of a pipeline, and processes to its left or right get killed.

Comment: I still don't get why you think `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` can't fail. BTW, `fgets` returns a null pointer when fails, not `EOF`.

Comment: Input operations fail once they run out if input. Output operations can easily be made to fail by closing the output file.

Comment: I updated the example to reflect an output operation.

Comment: The standard I/O Streams can be redirected to/from files. Hence, the same restrictions can apply

Comment: @Mat In the case where the program is in a pipeline, would the program not simply stall waiting for the operation to complete rather than fail?

Comment: @king_nak I believe a file redirection forks the process and replaces the stdout stream with the redirected file stream. I tested this out on a Debian 7.7 machine; the `fputs` call did not return a negative value despite a "permission denied" error displayed by bash.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: a write to a pipe whose reader was killed (assuming SIGPIPE was handled) will error out with EPIPE, it won't block forever waiting for a reader that can't possibly come back. I don't think C goes into this level of detail though, but certainly won't guarantee that reads or writes can't fail.

Comment: No input/output operations can be guaranteed in advance due to their intrinsic nature : they operate with an outside world, and the program cannot control the its outside; so their is always potential problems that may occur during input/output (disk full, terminal closed, network down, etc).

Comment: Let me clarify what appears to be ambiguous to me: I do not believe that the C standard can guarantee that operation calls on standard I/O streams will complete successfully, but rather that if they do complete that they will return successful return values. The reason I suspect this may be this case is that when I induce an I/O error in my development environment, rather than return an error value, these operation calls either stall or do not complete at all before the process is terminated.

Comment: It is very possible that the C standard is silent on these possibilities. I simply want to verify whether or not there is any information in the standard regarding these specific situations and the behavior I am witnessing on my development environment.

Comment: you ask two questions: 1) what does the manual say?  perhaps you should read the manual for the answer 2) can an I/O on stdin or stdout fail?  please read @jean-baptiste comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard IO streams are guaranteed to exist. They are not guaranteed to be open at the time of an IO operation. As a process generally inherits its IO streams from its parent (be it a shell or anything else) they can be in absolutely any state : directly to the console/keyboard, redirected to/from files or pipes or sockets, or ... closed.

So yes, you can get an error on any IO operation even on standard streams, and either on input (closed) or output (no more space on device, ...)

Edit :

You mention a special case for `perror` which has a void return type. It does not mean that perror cannot fail : it can if it is redirected. But the problem is more *where can I write that I could not write an error condition* ?! As it is already in a error handler, if it cannot write the result of perror, normally the program cannot do better :-(

Comment: I think section **7.19.3** paragraph **7** guarantees that all three standard I/O streams are initially open. Does this mean that some time after the main function begins, these streams may be closed?

Comment: It does appear passing standard streams to `fclose` is legal: [How to close stdout and stderr in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972994/how-to-close-stdout-and-stderr-in-c)

Comment: The case of `perror` is a concern since it provides no way to verify if an error has occurred -- an error is possible in the case of lack of space if `freopen` is called on `stderr` to redirect its output to a file for example. However, that may be best answered in a separate dedicated StackOverflow question; I believe there is enough implicit in the standard to argue that read/write errors are possible for standard streams.