# Redirecting STDIN/OUT/ERR

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a linux daemon in c and found some [sample code on this page](http://www.4pmp.com/2009/12/a-simple-daemon-in-c/).

I understand all the code except where it tries to redirect STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR (to /dev/null/). I also found a number of questions on here related to **why** these should be redirected (which I understand).

Specifically the section of code my question relates to is:

```
/* Route I/O connections */

/* Open STDIN */
i = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);

/* STDOUT */
dup(i);

/* STDERR */
dup(i);
```

Reading the [man page for dup()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/dup.htm) it implies that `dup()` simply duplicates a file descriptor.

So I don't understand how this does the redirect ? Is the compiler taking hints from the comments in the line above ?, or is it missing some code ?, is it plain wrong ?, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Did that example close the existing STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR before creating new ones?  So that the next free fd to use would be 0, then 1, then 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR to /dev/null in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263173/redirecting-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-dev-null-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's import to understand the previous bit of the example code you link to:

```
/* close all descriptors */
        for (i = getdtablesize(); i >= 0; --i)
        {
            close(i);
        }
```

This closes all open file descriptors including `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

As the manpage for `open()` states

> The file descriptor returned by a successful call will be the lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process

So the subsequent call to `open()` in the example code will redirect file descriptor `0` which is `STDIN`, to `/dev/null`.

The subsequent calls to `dup()` will duplicate the file descriptor using the next lowest numbers. `STDOUT` is `1`, and `STDERR` is `2`.

The manpage for `dup()` states:

> The dup() system call creates a copy of the file descriptor oldfd, using the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of dup:

> The dup(oldfd) system call creates a copy of the file descriptor oldfd,
>   using the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor.

If you see the referenced code, he is first closing all the open file descriptors:

```
      for (i = getdtablesize(); i >= 0; --i)
         {
            close(i);
         }
```

After that when you call `dup(i)`, it will copy the file descriptor i to the lowest available descriptor, which will be 0 (`stdin`). Doing that again will copy it to descriptor 1 (`stdout`) and similarly for descriptor 2 (`stderr`). In this way, the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` of the daemon process are pointing to `/dev/null`.

Every process gets three open file descriptors which are the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` (these descriptors usually have the values 0, 1, and 2 respectively). When you call `printf()`, for example, it writes to the file pointed to by the `stdout` descriptor. By pointing this descriptor to another file (such as `/dev/null`), any output from this process will get redirected to that file. Same logic applies for `stdin` and `stderr`.

On the shell, when you run something like `ls > ls.out`, the shell does the same. It `fork()`s a new process, opens ls.out for writing, and calls `dup` (or `dup2`) to copy the file descriptor of `ls.out` to this process' stdout.